# Custom Hexagonal SKTileSet's Tile don't fit the SKTileMap's Hexes

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, hexagonal-tiles, sktilemapnode

So I've been trying trying to make an SKTileMap using the xcode editor.
I have downloaded the assets from [here](https://opengameart.org/content/hexagon-tiles-93x).
Put everything in my assets, and created an empty tileset that I filled with the tiles.
Now when I go make the tile map on my sks file, the tiles don't fit the map at all, like shown [on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b826h.jpg).
I tried changing the size of my tiles which gives me a better looking result, however the textures are not centered on the hexes [like you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqE9S.jpg).

So I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious, but I couldn't find any tutorials on adding custom hex tiles online. Anyone knows how I should proceed?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem or incompatibility here are the images.

For SKTileMap node using a *Hexagonal Pointy SpriteKit Tile Set* the images should have a super-specific ratio like a top view. If you see the Apple example:

[image]

Of course, you can try to simulate the camera/isometric effect but the hexagons should have the right size. If you compare both tiles it has completely different points of view.

[image]

If you transform the image to right aspect, can get some like this:

[image]

I'm not really an expert on * Hexagonal Pointy SpriteKit Tile Set * and I couldn't find more documentation about it, I hope @Knight0fDragon can guide us a little more.

Comment: So basically I can't use any assets that aren't the exact ratio in xcode ?